# Is there an official email form widget or block?

Tags: widgets, forms, email, block-editor

I want to add an email form to a wordpress site, but all of the existing ones I see are from third parties.
Doesn't Wordpress offer an official email form to add as a widget or block?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no official email form block or widget.

[JetPack](https://jetpack.com/) has a [Form Block](https://jetpack.com/support/jetpack-blocks/form-block/) though.

JetPack is not "official", but is developed by the same people who run WordPress *.com*, so it is as close to an “official” block that you’ll get, even though they are *not* the official developers of the WordPress software itself, and you’ll need to install a plugin and connect to a WordPress.com account to use it.